# Paperclip dimension for images without cropping the image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Can any one give the dimension for the image without cropping that are used in paperclip. Any other symbols avaliable rather # and >.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paperclip uses the ImageMagick library to process images so you can use any option that ImageMagick provides. The full listing is here: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/

So you can do things like:

```
has_attached_file :photo,
                  :styles => {
                    :thumb => "100x100!",
                    :small  => "150x150^",
                    :medium => "50%" }
```

etc.

You should spend some time reading through the commands to find the right one for your case.